# Eliminating a Proxy by network bridging?

Tags: proxy, bridge

I have a network in my work office that runs through an especific local proxy, but we acquired a device that does not work with proxys. I'm very new to networks, and it took me a while to realize this was the problem. The thing is that we can't have internet outside this proxy. So, my idea was using an old PC with fedora we had, with 2 ethernet ports and "Bridge" (if I'm using the right term) this connection and let the computer manage the proxy settings leaving the other port for this device, but every bridging setup I found just transported the proxy settings with it. I must say, the problem with this device is not the running through the proxy itself, its just that there is no place to configure it (on purpose, according to the manufacturers). I would appreciate any help :).